# Pure OwnValue Functions vs Patterned DownValue Functions

Tags: downvalues

Is it better to use pure `Function` assigned to symbols as their `OwnValues` vs function defined by patterns as symbol's `DownValues`.

Which one is faster and are there any exceptions?

Comment: Pure functions are often a bit faster, but defining functions by patterns as `DownValues` is more flexible. For example, this allows for overloading of functions and in combination with `TagSetDelayed`, you an implement your own  "classes" (in the sense of object oriented programming).

Comment: there is no better or worse, they have different use cases, Henriks comment only mentions some of the differences. I'm quite confident that you can find exceptions to the speed question as well :-)

Comment: I also believe your question is completely answered by the one that @xzczd linked.